# Why gather stats on all columns?

Tags: greenplum

Is there a good reason why I should not turn the column statistics down to 0 on columns that are not used in `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, or window functons etc.?

It strikes me that the default statistics target is only there for people who can't be bothered to set the statistics target to either something high for `JOIN` and `WHERE` columns, and 0 for everything else. Am I wrong?